# Why does my AlertDialogue in flutter throws error even though everything looks fine?

Tags: flutter

This is my code which contains a button named Alert and when I click on button a alert should appear.But The screen is loaded properly with a button in Center but as soon as I click button it gives error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Hello());
}

class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hello({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: const Text('Close'),
                            )
                          ],
                          title: const Text('Alert Check'),
                          content: const Text('Alert Box has Appear!!'),
                          contentPadding:const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        ));
              },
              child: const Text('Alert')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error says :Exception caught by gesture

The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:

```
No MaterialLocalizations found.
MyApp widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
The material library uses Localizations to generate messages, labels, and abbreviations.
To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a MaterialApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why this is happenning, but I would take a chance and say that is a race condition initializing the widget, if you just place `runApp` inside another class it works fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const Hello(),
    );
  }
}

class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hello({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: const Text('Close'),
                            )
                          ],
                          title: const Text('Alert Check'),
                          content: const Text('Alert Box has Appear!!'),
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        ));
              },
              child: const Text('Alert')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I issue was about BuildContext. creating new widget provide separate context and solves the issue.